# How to name a model checkpoint with a metric involving a period?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, filenames

I would like to name my checkpoint like so:

```py
mcp_save = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('effnet-{epoch:02d}-{val_f0.5-score:.4f}.mdl_wts.hdf5', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_f0.5-score', mode='max')
```

But because the metric has a period I get an error when it tried to save

> 'Failed to format this callback filepath: "effnet-{epoch:02d}-{val_f0.5-score:.4f}.mdl_wts.hdf5". Reason: 'val_f0''

The metric is from *segmentation_models* pypi package.

```
fscore = sm.metrics.FScore(beta=0.5)
```

I can see the name while it is logged out by tensorflow:

> 1000/1000 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6205 - accuracy: 0.2607 - f0.5-score: 0.3066

Is there a way to escape the period or provide a different string such that it can save the filename with the score?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I can rename the metric so that it is usable.

> fscore = sm.metrics.FScore(beta=0.5, name='myfscore')

Then rename it in the checkpointer

> mcp_save = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('effnet-{epoch:02d}-{myfscore:.4f}.mdl_wts.hdf5', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_myfscore', mode='max')